# How should I populate JSON data in a Django template?

Tags: jquery, python, django

I need to grab the  data from the url like this

`http://www.example.com/data?format=json`

and its output will be like

```
student_details: {
    terms: {
        subjects: {
            assigments: {
                id:11, name:"ass_1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Above is not the valid json and it's just an example to show how the json will be like.

I want to know what's the best way to show the above data in a detail view page.

I mean do I need to code every column and and put a place holder there?
Or should I have one column and loop through the all of the rows?

How should I do it?

I am also confused about how I should display the nested subjects, terms assigments, etc.

If someone can point me in the right direction that'd be good.

EDIT:
Django will be creating the JSON. What I need is to generate the detail page only in jquery or html. I don't want to include any server side rendering. It will be a static html page but getting its data from JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON is nearly synonymous to a list of dictionaries in Python, so there's nothing special you need to do to iterate over the key: value pairs in a Django template. Sounds like you need to get familiar with the Django template language, especially the `{% for %}` tag: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#for

Comment: sorry i didn't mention . The django will be creating the json. but i need to generate the detail page only in jquery or html. i don't want to include any server side. it will static html page but getting its data from json

Comment: Ah. Then you'll need to loop over your JSON with jQuery and inject the  keys/values you want into the HTML, or create it as you go. Alternatively, you might want to take a look at http://handlebarsjs.com/ if you want a completely JavaScript-based solution.

Comment: @Brandon the link you provided is not found.

Comment: @user2253546 Updated

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, I don't think what you want to do can be done since, as you said, you don't want to include any server side works. Django template rendering happens on the server side of things, and by the time jQuery gets your django-generated JSON the template has already been rendered, delivered back to the client and presented in a browser.

I would recommend you find a similar templating solution, but client-side, like [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org). What you'll want to do is define the HTML template you'd want to populate with the JSON, and on the success callback of your ajax call, insert the its rendered result on the DOM.